# Phaser sprite scaling different in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

When running the same script on both firefox and chrome, invisible sprites scale differently.

The following image is correct, and what I want to be rendered. This is in firefox.

[image: Phaser on Firefox]

This image is in chrome. As you can see, the invisible sprites are much larger, but everything else is scaling correctly.

[image: Phaser on Chrome]

This is the code that I am running:

```
finishLine = game.add.sprite(256, 500);
finishLine.scale.x = 256;
finishLine.scale.y = 1;
finishLine.enableBody = true;
game.physics.enable(finishLine, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
finishLine.body.immovable = true;

canLap = game.add.sprite(256, 560);
canLap.scale.x = 256;
canLap.scale.y = 1;
canLap.enableBody = true;
game.physics.enable(canLap, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
canLap.body.immovable = true;
```

My game object is being created as follows:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(1280, 720, Phaser.CANVAS, '');
```

Has anyone seen this before, or do you think I have stumbled upon a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that this issue is not actually an issue with Chrome as I originally expected. It is actually an issue when rendering sprite scaling on Firefox when the debug console window is open. As such, I have created a  [Bug Report](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/2756) for this issue.